# Angular2 modify *ngFor rows individually after rendering

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

I'm wanting to access each row of my repeater after it's been rendered say from a button click or something similar. Whats the Angular 2 way of doing this?

Thank in advance

```html
<section class="section">
  <article class="article" *ngFor="let item of slides; let i = index">
    <figure class="figure" *ngIf="item.show">
      <img src="{{item.image}}" alt="{{item.description}}"/>
      <figcaption>{{item.description}}</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </article>
  <mySlideShow style="display:block;clear:both;" [aList]="slides">click me</mySlideShow>
</section>
```

Edit:

So I add a public boolean "show" and the initialised it during the  ngOnInit() phase. I then have a click event which passes in the object and then I increment by index.

Comment: What do you want to change?

Answer (score 0):

I know this sounds like an obvious one, but just pass the `item` as a parameter to your `(click)` method.

```html
<div (click)="onDivClick(item)">Click me!</div>
```

If you change anything in that item, you probably have to manually call change detection though.

```js
constructor(private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

// ...

onDivClick(item: ISlide): void {
    item.description = "some new description";
    changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
}
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the answers. Im wanting to toggle the visibility of the items from an event outside the *ngFor. I saw a few posts that refer to a  child view but not really sure if this is the way to do iy

Comment: I doubt you have to actually activate detect changes because angular cycles through, correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @misha130 it does, but in arrays only on the first level, so if you change the description in the second level, it won't detect it automagically.